# Can you Install Ubuntu Phone OS on Alcatel 5020n?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android

Hidy ho all,

I have this old crappy smart phone, and I wanted to try and get another OS on it, and see if it ran better.  Its currently running Android 4.1.2, and (last time I checked) had an unlocked boot loader.  Mind you, this was years ago, and I can't even remember how to check nowadays.

If you don't want to look up the specs, I have some of them here:
Alcatel Onetouch 5020n
512Mb of RAM
1.0 GHz Cortex-A9 (Dual Core processor)
4 GB of internal space (of which, 2 are available to the user)

If I read correctly, these are the minimum specs for the OS.  But again, my memory could be failing me.

So, simple enough question.  Can my phone run this operating system?  And, if so, where should one look for installing an new operating system on an old phone?